# Scala map not iterating to all elements

Tags: scala

I am trying to search the list of trees for a given state in a file using Scala.

Here is the sample file(tab separated):-

```
Quercus acerifolia  mapleleaf oak   MN
Quercus _acutidens      CA
Quercus acutissima  sawtooth oak    AL,GA,LA,MD,MS,NC,PA,VA
Quercus agrifolia   California live oak CA
Quercus alba    white oak    AL,AR,CT,DC,DE,FL,GA,IA,IL,IN,KS,KY,LA
Quercus ajdfensis   Ajo Mountain scrub oak ,MN
```

My Code:-

```
//declaring package
package HW10

//declaring object
object TreesStub {

//importing Source package for files import
  import scala.io.Source

  //assigning the file path to filename variable
  val fileName = "trees.tsv"

  //defining Main function
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //reading source file from a file which is tabe separated
    val treeList: List[String] = Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.toList

    //calling searchTrees method for a given State
    searchTrees("MN", treeList)

    //searchTrees method logic for a given State and print it
    def searchTrees(state: String, trees: List[String]): Unit = {

      //defining mutable empty map collection as "states"
      var states = collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()

      //Searching the tree list for a given state and adding the map and //tree list to the states map collection

    trees.map(x => (x.split("\t", -1))).filter((_.length > 2)).map(x =>

        //using try catch block for handling match not found exception
        try {
        if (x(2).contains(state)) states += (state -> x(0))
      }
      catch {
        //exception if caught to None
        case e: Exception => println(s"None")
      })
      //printing map "states" values
      states.foreach(println)
    }
  }
}
```

The output i am getting as :- `(MN,Quercus acerifolia)`

Expected output:-(statename, tree list)

```
(MN,Quercus acerifolia)
(MN,Quercus ajdfensis)
```

I am able to print only one match not able to print all the matches. Not sure what is wrong in the code? Looks like the map is iterating only once not for all the matches. Please let me know how to print for all the matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`states` is a map, a data structure that maps each key to a *a single value*.  So a map is the wrong data structure to use if you want to accumulate multiple results for the same key.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think you are right i thought map will allow mutiple values for single key in scala which is not the case. We need multi map for this.I handled using list.

Answer (score 1):

```
Quercus acerifolia  mapleleaf oak   MN
Quercus _acutidens      CA
Quercus acutissima  sawtooth oak    AL,GA,LA,MD,MS,NC,PA,VA
Quercus agrifolia   California live oak CA
Quercus alba    white oak    AL,AR,CT,DC,DE,FL,GA,IA,IL,IN,KS,KY,LA
Quercus ajdfensis   Ajo Mountain scrub oak ,MN
```

Have you tried searching for something other than `MN`?
Your last line is `,MN` which is probably messing with your string comparison.

Comment: Yes i tried using the "searchTrees("AL", treeList)" got only one match. Expected two matches. I don't think so last record is an issue i tried removing that and same issue.

Comment: If you search for ",MN" you will find the other occurrence. The problem is that List#contains only matches an exact String and you want to match a string containing a string. That means that what you want to do is search inside each string.

Comment: Yes i just want to search for lines which contains the "State Name" provided and add the tree list to the Map. The problem is just giving me the first match. If i remove the match which i got from my input file and run i am getting the other match. I think it's just giving the first match not all the matches.